# How to use Travis CI to test on both Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and CentOS7 in one .travis.yml file?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I have some ansible playbooks that I want to test on two different Linux distros. (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and CentOS 7)

I understand how to configure a `.travis.yml` to test on Ubuntu 14.04 since TravisCI provides a built-in container for Ubuntu.

And for CentOS 7, I understand I need to use Docker to build a CentOS 7 container within TravisCI so I can test my code on CentOS.

Also, I know how to test, for example, both CentOS 6 and CentOS7 together via using `matrix`.

However, I don't know how to have one test with two builds and one is on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, the other one is on CenOS 7. So I can test two different Linux distros at one time

Any hints or examples of `.travis.yml` that can illustrate what I want would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, something like this would provide a container for both Ubuntu 14.04 and CentOS7 for your Travis CI job:

```
# setup environment
dist: trusty
sudo: required
language: python

# setup container matrix
matrix:
  include:
    - env: OS='ubuntu:14.04'
    - env: OS='centos:7'

before_install:
  - docker pull $OS

install:
  - docker run -d $OS /bin/sh -c "provision container if you do not have a prebuilt image and are instead using base images"

script:
  - docker run -d $OS /bin/sh -c "ansible tests"
```

This will get you going with tests on both operating systems with Travis CI.

However, it would probably be easier to just use Molecule: https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

You can specify the Docker images for both inside the `molecule/scenario/tests/molecule.yml`, install molecule within Travis CI in `install:`, and then just `molecule test` in your `script:` to do the heavy lifting for you.

Update: Travis has posted a blog article on this topic where they use the approach I outlined above. Check it for even more information: https://blog.travis-ci.com/2017-11-30-testing-ansible-roles-using-docker-on-travis

Comment: Thanks so much Matt! I will try it out and make sure to give feedback (AC). Thanks for suggesting the `Molecule` and it looks really cool!

Comment: @Lucas Coincidentally, Travis just published a blog article on this topic where they basically do what I wrote above: https://blog.travis-ci.com/2017-11-30-testing-ansible-roles-using-docker-on-travis. However, they are also  using the containers for non-acceptance testing, which is rather inefficient. Their approach at a low-level is sub-optimal but functional.